# Forcing an ultrahomogeneous structure in a non-relational language

Tags: logic, model-theory, forcing

The "longer" Hodges has the following exercise (8.2.10):

> Let $L$ be a *finite relational* signature and $K$ a non-empty class of
>   $L$-structures which has HP, JEP and AP. Let $T$ be the theory of
>   structures whose age is $\subseteq K$. Show that the Fraisse limit of $K$ is an
>   enforceable model of $T$.

The emphasis is mine.  If I were to believe the Gricean maxims, I would assume that this is not generally true of a functional language $L$.  In fact, I can kind of see that how adding relations in other stages of the construction messes up what you do with partial isomorphisms.

Is there an illuminating example of such a theory $T$ in a functional language where the Fraisse limit is not enforceable?

*Addendum*: The construction here is analogous to the proof of the omitting types theorem or any other Henkin-type constructions.  We expand $L$ with countably many constants to obtain $L^+$.  We construct an $\omega$-chain $(T_i)$ of finite sets of literals in $L^+$ that are consistent with $T$ by stages.  A player $E$ is assigned an infinite-coinfinite subset $X_E$ of $\omega$ and is responsible for saying what $T_i$ is for $i \in X_E$.  Finally, we build the so-called canonical model $A$ of $T^+ := \bigcup_i T_i$ from the terms made up of the constants occurring in $T$ and taking the quotient by the relations following from $T + T^+$.

A property $P$ of the structure $A$ being built by forcing is *enforceable* if the player responsible for that property has a winning strategy (where a win for her is to have $A$ satisfy $P$);  a structure $M$ is enforceable if the property of being isomorphic to $M$ is enforceable.

Comment: I don't have big Hodges at the moment - what does "enforceable" mean?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Please see my edit.

Comment: And what's the game - alternately building finite extensions?

Comment: If so, would the analogous game for functional languages consist of playing finite structures with partial functions, or finitely-generated structures?

Comment: @NoahSchweber See my further edit; hopefully this is descriptive enough...

Comment: Separately, what happens if the players together wind up playing "$f(c_0)\not=c_i$" for each $i$? At every stage this looks legal, but at the end of the day the set of constant symbols doesn't form a structure. (Note that this is avoided in the situation where we play bigger and bigger finitely generated structures, although that has its own issues.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I filled in the details I missed.  I guess not all elements of $A$ is not named by a constant.

Comment: OK, that clears that up. What about my more recent comment?

Comment: OK, how do we guarantee appropriate completeness? E.g. if one player puts "$f(c_0)=f(c_1)\vee f(c_0)=f(c_2)$" into the theory but neither player picks a conjunct, what do we do? In the relational case we can on move $i$ have the appropriate player play a *full quantifier-free diagram* on $\{c_0,..., c_i\}$, but here that would involve infinitely many sentences.

Comment: (I guess we could demand that on move $i$ the truth value of the $i$th quantifier free sentence in the language has to be determined?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber You caught yet another error of mine; I meant literals with no variables instead of quantifier-free sentences.

Comment: What's a literal - is that an atomic or negated atomic sentence? (If so, I'm happy now.)

Comment: Finally, what's an age for functional languages? If it's a set of finitely generated structures, then the answer is clear: taking $K$ to be the set of all finitely generated abelian groups, the Fraisse limit of $K$ has lots of elements of infinite order but "every element has finite order" is enforceable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You are right about the definition of ages.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this comes down to how we treat ages and Fraisse limits in functional languages.

The direct analogue of ages in the functional case is to talk about **finitely generated structures**. However, this winds up clashing horribly with enforceability, which is instead about finitely *approximated* structures. For example, take $K$ to be the class of all finitely generated abelian goups. Then we can appropriately form the (analogue of the) Fraisse limit of $K$, and unless I'm missing something it's just $(\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Q})\oplus (\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ - certainly it has many elements of infinite order. But in the corresponding game, player $2$ can enforce that every element has finite order (and, again unless I'm missing something, $\bigoplus_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is enforceable).

For relational structures, though, there's no difference between "finitely generated" and "finite" so this issue doesn't arise.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Noah's answer: In Fraïssé theory settings, it's common to assume we're working in a finite relational language. But usually what's actually important is the following (more technical) consequence: **For every $n$, there are only finitely many isomorphism types of $n$-generated structures in $K$.** Let's call this condition $(\star)$.

Here an $n$-generated structure is a structure $A$ and an $n$-tuple $\overline{a}$ such that $A = \langle\overline{a}\rangle$, and an isomorphism of $n$-generated structures $(A,\overline{a})\cong (B,\overline{b})$ is an isomorphism $\sigma\colon A\to B$ such that $\sigma(\overline{a}) = \overline{b}$.

If $T$ is the theory of structures with age contained in $K$, then an isomorphism class of $n$-generated structures in $K$ is essentially the same as a complete quantifier-free type in $n$ free variables consistent with $T$. So $(\star)$ is equivalent to **for every $n$, there are only finitely many complete quantifier-free $n$-types consistent with $T$.**

This condition is exactly what's needed to prove that the theory of the Fraïssé limit of $K$ is $\aleph_0$-categorical and has quantifier elimination, and I believe it's also sufficient to prove that the Fraïssé limit is enforceable in Hodges's sense. I think Hodges is just trying to keep things simple by saying "finite relational", which is a non-technical condition that everyone understands.

Note that in a relational language, every $n$-generated structure has size at most $n$, so $(\star)$ just asserts that there are only finitely many structures of each size in $K$ up to isomorphism. This is trivial if the language is finite, but may fail in an infinite language.

As soon as we add function symbols, $(\star)$ has more teeth. It implies that for all $n$, there is a finite upper bound $N$ on the size of $n$-generated structures: otherwise, there infinitely many terms $(t_i)_{i\in \omega}$ such that the formulas $t(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_{n+1}$ are pairwise non-equivalent modulo $T$, and hence there are infinitely many quantifier-free $(n+1)$-types consistent with $T$. In particular, $(\star)$ implies every finitely generated structure in $K$ is finite - as Noah pointed out, this is not the case in the class of abelian groups!

If the language is finite, $(\star)$ is equivalent to the above condition: **for all $n$, there is a finite upper bound $N$ on the size of $n$-generated structures.**

Here are some examples:

- Consider the (infinite, relational) language with one $n$-ary relation $R_n$ for each $n$. The class of all finite structures in this language does not satisfy $(\star)$, since there are $2^{\aleph_0}$ $1$-generated structures: for each $n$, we can choose independently whether $R_n(a,a,\dots,a)$ holds.
- Now let $K$ be a class of finite structures in the language above such that if $R_n(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ holds, then $a_i\neq a_j$ for all $1\leq i < j \leq n$ (e.g. the class such that each $R_n$ is a hypergraph relation). Then $K$ satisfies $(\star)$, since only the relations $R_1,\dots,R_n$ can be nontrivial on an $n$-generated structure.
- The class of finite Boolean algebras satisfies $(\star)$, since the language is finite, and an $n$-generated Boolean algebra has size at most $2^{2^n}$.
- The class of finite fields of charcteristic $p$ does not satisfy $(\star)$: every finite field has cyclic multiplicative group, so every finite field of characterstic $p$ can be $1$-generated.